# Universal App Rejected and Some IAP get rejected again and again

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an app that buttons and images and icons set for only representational purposes. My friend is making better ones and so my app is not finished yet but apple said that I have 30 days to submit a binary or my app will be deleted from the iTunes connect. So i uploaded my binary and here is the rejection message.

> 10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good it may be rejected
>
> 10.6
>   We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>
> It would be appropriate to add additional functionality to the application in order to enhance the user’s experience. For ideas on how to improve
>   the user’s experience, you may wish to review the User Experience
>   Guidelines section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.
>
> It would also be appropriate to differentiate, either in the Application Description or in the app, which purchases are consumable and which ones are non-consumable.
>
> For technical assistance, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Depending on your questions, be sure to include any crash logs, screenshots, or steps to reproduce the issues you’ve encountered.
>
> These examples identify types of issues discovered in your app but may not represent all such issues. It would be appropriate to thoroughly evaluate your app to address these types of issues.

When I add icons, images and button images after my friend finishes them, my app would be approved right ? Is this the message that I should get from 10.6 ? And what does this message mean with

> It would also be appropriate to differentiate, either in the Application Description or in the app, which purchases are consumable and which ones are non-consumable.

I have one non-consumable IAP and that is pro version IAP. All the others are consumable. I think it is clear that pro version is non-consumable because it has a restore button.

Last thing I want to ask is, since I uploaded a binary my app won't get deleted from iTunes connect right? My app is rejected but I uploaded a binary in time, anyone knows about this ?

Comment: I would heavily advise you to ask all your questions directly to Apple through iTunes Connect. When Apple rejects an app, they open this channel so you can argue and ask everything you need to get your app approved.

Comment: I asked apple already but i wanted to know if there is any other person who have been through these steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will not review incomplete or in test apps as the app store is not the place for testing. Really you should not create an app on iTunes connect until you are ready to submit to the app store.

I would suggest that most likely the app will not get deleted as you have submitted a binary but don't count on it especially as the version you submitted is incomplete and Apple may decide that therefore you still haven't submitted a proper app and delete it all the same

Even if you contact Apple they will not tell you if the app will be approved when the buttons are added. It is their policy to only review what you put in front of them and not to speculate on what will get through.

There are no guarantees that your app will get through the app store when the buttons are added, but you stand a much better chance as your app is complete. It will also depend on if you have followed all of Apple's rules and are not trying to do anything illegal.

I will be tempted to put your non consumable item in a separate section to clearly mark it and make it easier to get the app approved.

Comment: I am not testing my app, my app is finished and working exactly as i wanted but there are many image's (like buttons and views) looks horrible.. I just put them a "Loading" text to remind me to change them in the future. All wanted to know is what these messages from apple means. I mean are these only visual ? Or also i need to change any code ?

Comment: What they have said is that your visuals are not good enough for the app store therefore they are rejecting the app. Apple don't like apps that don't look nice or look unfinished. Chances are you will only need to change the visuals not your code but there is no guarantee as they most likely have not tested the app or even looked at the code if they don't think the visuals are good enough.

Comment: what you say is not true. One has to create the app on iTunesConnect to test it. There is the only way to test in-app purchases, for example, specially with content hosted with apple.